# The action you have requested is invalid in Zoo Visitor

Tags: zoo-visitor, registration

I am using Zoo Visitor registration with inline error message. if I submit the registration form with some empty fields, it shows inline errors correctly but while submitting again I am getting the EE error message *The action you have requested is invalid.*, which seems odd.

Please see the attachment for this EE error message.

[image]

Comment: In the page source is their an xid value?

Comment: @dadonbike Thanks for your input. I have checked page(s) source XID value is there as hidden field.

Comment: Have you upgraded to latest version of visitor? V1.3.28.

Comment: @LloydHill I am using v1.3.29 which is latest.

Comment: Not really a fix, but turning off "Process form data in Secure Mode?" in the security settings addressed the issue for me. Not an ideal solution by any means! I would guess it's because the XID isn't getting updated when you're returned to the form with inline errors.

Comment: @TimJukes thanks for your input. Yes, you are right. It's not an idea solution. I have already did your solution and its working fine. EE Zoo should fix this issue.